# Firestore Update Error: Using arrayUnion in Firestore Update Operation

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to update a Firestore document by adding an element to an array field using Firestore's 'arrayUnion' method. I'm using Firestore in my Angular application with AngularFire, and the specific error I'm encountering is:

> Type 'FieldValue' is missing the following properties from type 'CarAttachment[]': length, pop, push, concat

> The expected type comes from property 'attachments,' which is declared here on type 'Partial'.

Here's the relevant code snippet I'm using for this operation:

```js
addCarAttachment(carId: string, attachment: CarAttachment) {
  return this.firestore.collection<Car>('car').doc(carId).update({
    attachments: FieldValue.arrayUnion(attachment),
  });
}
```

Additionally, I have defined the following interfaces for 'Car' and 'CarAttachment':

```js
export interface Car {
    id: string;
    attachments: CarAttachment[];
    created_at: Date | Timestamp;
    updated_at?: Date | Timestamp;
}

export interface CarAttachment {
    doc_name: string;
    doc_url: string;
    doc_type: string;
    expiration_time: Date | Timestamp;
    uploaded_at: Date | Timestamp;
}
```

I'm seeking advice or solutions to help me overcome this error and successfully update my Firestore document by adding an element to the 'attachments' array field using 'arrayUnion' while using AngularFire.

Comment: addCarAttachment(carId: string, attachment: CarAttachment) gets CarAttachment while your Interface has and array of CarAttachment, CarAttachment[]. The update method expecting Car with CarAttachment[]. U can set the Update<any>

Comment: @HezyZiv Yes you are right, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hezy Ziv said I need just to use any in the addCarAttachment

```js
addCarAttachment(carId: string, attachment: CarAttachment) {
  return this.firestore.collection<any>('car').doc(carId).update({
    attachments: FieldValue.arrayUnion(attachment),
  });
}
```